# What force does work on the block in following question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, work

[image: Figure - 1]
[image: Figure - 2]
[image: Figure - 3]

In Figure 1, I have shown the initial position of a block of mass $M$ with circular track and at start of the track is a cylinder of mass $m$ . Now initially the system is at rest. All surfaces are smooth. Now when the cylinder is released then due to gravitational pull it will start to move down. And now, since there is external force on the block in y direction which is Normal force from ground hence momentum won't be conserved in y direction but since there is no net force in the x direction on the system hence the momentum is conserved in x direction. (Assume general system of x and y coordinates which is generally taken in mathematics). Now as the cylinder gains velocity in +ve x direction, to conserve momentum the block will have to gain velocity in -ve x direction. But here's the problem. The only force acting on the block in x direction is normal force (component of normal force) from the cylinder but since for every infinitesimal displacement of cylinder, the normal force is perpendicular to it and hence there should be no net negative work done on the cylinder by normal force then how would it do positive work on the block?

Now I did some research work on this and went deep into my brain simulating the situation and I partially got the answer by myself(I believe that this is the answer which may or may not be wrong) and the answer is the relative displacement. When the cylinder moves then for every infinitesimal displacement of cylinder there would be a displacement of the block and hence relative displacement of the cylinder would not be exactly perpendicular to normal force. But the problem with this solution is that when the system was initially at rest then there was no displacement of block for any initial infinitesimal displacement of cylinder because the initial velocity of block was 0 but as long as there's no velocity of the block then there won't be work done on the block (because there won't be any displacement of block making normal force perpendicular to infinitesimal displacement of cylinder) and hence there won't be change of velocity so according to this logic there should be no final velocity of block which would violate the conservation of momentum.

**Edit**
Everyone was getting confused and hence I have put an image below describing the problem in short.Also $ds$ used in above formula is not same as $ds$ labelled in the image

[image]

Comment: What is the problem asking for?

Comment: @BobD  The problem is that work done by internal force is always 0 and hence if the Normal force done work on the block then it should do equal amount of negative work on cylinder. But at exactly initial moment, there no displacement of block due to 0 velocity and hence normal force is perpendicular to small displacement made by cylinder and hence 0 work done by normal force on cylinder and so 0 work done on block and hence block wouldn't move at all violating conservation of momentum

Comment: Sorry, can't make any sense of what you are saying. Good luck!

Comment: @BobD Thanks for trying, wish you all the good in your life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear if you are asking about the work done on the block or the work done on a system consisting of both the block and the cylinder. I am assuming that you are talking about the block only. Note that this means that the contact force with the cylinder is not an internal force.

There are three external forces acting on the block. The normal force from the ground is vertically upward and the gravitational force from the earth is vertically downward. Since all motion is horizontal for both these forces $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v = 0$ at all times. So they do no work. In contrast, the contact force is at an angle $\theta$ from the vertical, so it has a horizontal component and thus $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v \ne 0$ except at the bottom.

> But the problem with this solution is that when the system was initially at rest then there was no displacement of block for any initial infinitesimal displacement of cylinder because the initial velocity of block was 0 but as long as there's no velocity of the block then there won't be work done on the block

This is not actually a problem. In fact, this always happens when accelerating from rest. Consider an external force that simply pushes on the left hand outside vertical face of the block. The momentum is $mv$ so the rate of change of the momentum is $\frac{d}{dt}m\vec v=m\dot {\vec v} = m\vec a=\vec F$, so the rate of change in momentum is independent of the velocity. In contrast the rate of change of the KE is $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{2} m v^2 = m \dot {\vec v} \cdot \vec v = \vec F \cdot \vec v$ so the rate of change of the KE depends on the velocity and goes to 0 as the velocity goes to 0.

This makes sense as 0 velocity is a minimum point for the KE and the rate of change is always 0 at a minimum. At zero velocity no work is being done even though the object is accelerating. Simply due to the fact that the KE is proportional to the square of the velocity.

Comment: Thanks for a response. What you stated as unclear, I want to clarify that first. I am talking about both the systems (the block and the cylinder) separately but talking of both. Work done on the block is only from Normal Force and I know that is is external force but we also know that if Normal force is putting in power on block then it must be deriving the same amount of power from cylinder. So this implies that there should be work done on cylinder as well by the normal force. And this is where it gets tricky.

Comment: I am completing the comment. And now since normal force has to do work on cylinder hence it should not be perpendicular to the displacement of cylinder and then only the normal force can derive power and deliver it to the block. But we know that the displacement of cylinder will be perpendicular to normal force as long as the block does not has any velocity. But initially block didn't had any velocity and having velocity is the cause of change of velocity of block but since no velocity present initially hence there should not be any change in velocity which would violate momentum conservation

Comment: @Ritanshu I addressed that issue directly already (the block not having initial velocity and therefore there is no initial change in KE)

Comment: Thanks, Got you